# Setting overlap ratio in PCL GICP and ICP methods

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

How can I set overlap ratio of two clouds for implemented Iterative Closest Point algorithms in Point Cloud Library?
There is a class like pcl::registration::CorrespondenceRejectorTrimmed but could not succeeded to use that in especially Generalized ICP method.

http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.0/classpcl_1_1registration_1_1_correspondence_rejector_trimmed.html

http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_generalized_iterative_closest_point.html

Comment: I see `setOverlapRadio (float ratio)` in the your first link. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i tried but could not get better result than generalized icp implementation

Comment: Would you add the core part of your code on your question? It would help us to how to improve the alignment performance. Also how much do two point cloud overlap approximately?